# Replicating a select element with a checkbox ul (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I'm trying to transform a fieldset with one legend and one UL of checkboxes/radio as a select html element. I know, it sounds bad and doesn't really make sense, but let's just say I have to do it.

I have a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/demj49st/

The problem is that I have some issues replicating the click behavior of the select element. I don't find the right selector to make it so a click on a checkbox wont make the fake select box disappear.

```
(function($) {

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('fieldset legend').on('click', function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.toggleClass('active');
            $this.next().toggleClass('visible');
        })


        $(document).on('click', function (e) {
            if($('ul').hasClass('visible') && !$('fieldset legend').is(e.target)) {
                $('ul').removeClass('visible');
                $('legend').removeClass('active');
            }
        });



    })

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('fieldset legend').on('click', function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.toggleClass('active');
            $this.next().toggleClass('visible');
        });


        $(document).on('click', function (e) {
           if (!$("fieldset > ul , fieldset > legend").is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
                && $("fieldset > ul , fieldset > legend").has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
            {

                $('fieldset > ul').removeClass('visible');
            }
        });

    });
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/demj49st/4/)

Comment: thanks, what is that nav_poster_options_add class though ?

Comment: @topleft sorry my bad .. this is just part of my code :) .. forgot to remove it :)